# How to iterate children of HTML element in JS

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="tilte">
        <div class="price">
            <input type="number" id="price" placeholder="price">
            <input type="number" id="taxes" placeholder="taxes">
            <input type="number" id="ads" placeholder="ads">
            <input type="number" id="discount" placeholder="discount">
</div>
```

i want to iterate over every element inside parent "inputs" of HTML into JS.
is there is a way to do this without error:

```js
let elements = ["title","price","taxes","ads","discount","total","count","category","submit"]
for ( i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i++ ){
    let elements[i] = document.querySelectorAll(elements["i"])
}
```

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. Also please provide the code in the question not a link to it. You can use `{}` and `<>` in the editor to format your code. If you use `<>`, you will create a *snippet* which will allow your code to be run. This makes it easier for people to help you with the code.

Comment: Do not put code in images; how can we help? We cannot copy and paste...

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: You can make an array and add the variables you have assigned by `array.push()` and then proceed with `for` or `foreach`

Comment: `getelementbyid` doesn’t exist. You mean [`getElementById`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Why not put all `<input>`s in a `<form>` and use the [`FormData` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)? Read the `valueAsNumber` property from the inputs.

Comment: can you write the solution ? show me how to use form data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Maybe you want to make your life a little easier with the selectors by id. If that's the case, you might like this approach:

```
const getElementById = (id = "") => {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

const getElementsById = (ids = []) => {
    return ids.map(getElementById);
};

const getElementsByIdMap = (ids = []) => {
    return Object.fromEntries(ids.map((id) => [id, getElementById(id)]));
};

const getElementValue = (el = {}) => {
    return el?.value;
};

const elements = getElementsById([
    "title",
    "price",
    "taxes",
    "ads",
    "discount",
    "total",
    "count",
    "category",
    "submit",
]);

elements.forEach((el) => {
    console.log(el);
});

const { title, price, taxes, ads, discount, total, count, category, submit } = getElementsByIdMap([
    "title",
    "price",
    "taxes",
    "ads",
    "discount",
    "total",
    "count",
    "category",
    "submit",
]);

const myFormElements = getElementsByIdMap(["title", "price", "taxes", "ads", "discount", "total", "count", "category"]);

getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault(); // maybe
    const values = Object.fromEntries(
        myFormElements.keys(myFormElements).map((key) => [key, getElementValue(myFormElements[key])])
    );

    console.log(values);
});
```

And one of the easiest hacks for HTML forms is this:

```
document.getElementById("submitFormId").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const values = Array.from(event.target)
        .slice(0, 8) // in your case there are 9 elements, last is submit with index 8 so we cut it
        .map((input) => input.value.trim()); // trim all the values to exclude spaces
    console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: i have edited the question, i  hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and get classes by using `.` e.g. `.my_class`, ids using `#` e.g. `#my_id` or html elements without any symbol, e.g. `input`.

For your case, to get all elements input from your class .inputs, would be like this:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs input');

inputs.forEach((element) => {
  // To get the value, you need to use .value
  console.log(element.value)
});
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="2" />
  <input type="text" value="3" />
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```